# Filter datatable against DataRow array

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with fields like so:

```
ID     startdate    enddate      price
2      03/26/2018   03/27/2018   100
56     03/26/2018   03/27/2018   85
88     03/27/2018   03/28/2018   12
14     03/27/2018   03/28/2018   66
```

and an array of datarows like so:

```
[2     03/26/2018  03/27/2018    100,
 25    03/27/2018  03/28/2018    66]
```

How can I remove out of the datatable the rows that lie on the same dates as the datarows but do no have the same IDs as the datarow array?

Answer (score 0):

so what I had done in order to accomplish this task is to first create a list of the ids from the array of datarow:

```
var targetIds = targetDataRows.Select(r => r.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();
```

then looped through the `targetDataRows` to get their specific dates and rows from the datatable that do not match the `targetIds` and remove them from the overall datatable

```
foreach(var row in targetDataRows)
{
     var startDate = (DateTime)row["startdate"];
     var endDate = (DateTime)row["enddate"];
     var nonMatchingRows = (from row in overallDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                            where !targetIds.Contains(row.Field<int>("ID")) && DateTime.Compare(row.Field<DateTime>("startdate"), startDate) == 0 && DateTime.Compare(row.Field<DateTime>("enddate"), endDate) == 0
                            select row).ToList();
     foreach(var nonMatchingRow in nonMatchingRows)
     {
           overallDataTable.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(nonMatchingRow);
     }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would do quite what you said in your OP? Doesn't `targetDataRows` contain all rows so `targetIds` contains all IDs so `nonMatchingRows` is always empty?

Comment: targetDataRows contains the rows that I want to keep in the overall larger datatable. I'm looping through the targetDataRows to get their dates and doing id matching against the targetIds list.